# How to handle modeling categorical variables where categories may change over time?

Tags: python, data-science, statsmodels

I am faced with a problem regarding a categorical variable. In my case, my variable may have varying number of levels. For example, suppose, my categorical variable represents `type_of_cars`. Initially, it had only three types (for argument's sake):`gas`,
`diesel` and `hybrid`. I have used an encoding to represent them. Now a new type of cars come to the market which is `eV` (for electric vehicle). I want to know if there is a way to accommodate EVs without retraining a model.

In my case, the categorical variable has roughly 50 different levels and new levels may be added as time goes on or old ones may be deleted. How do I go about modeling the data without retraining the entire model each time it happens, if it is at all possible?

Your suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to just retrain your model.

Thinking about how a categorical variable affects your model might be helpful. Categorical variables are generally treated a binary variables where each category is its own column, the row in that column is a 1 if that category is present and a 0 otherwise. Now imagine adding an additional column to your data for which your model has not been trained, as would be the case with a new category... this will result in sub-optimal performance. Most likely, this new column will have no affect on the model prediction.

There are examples of what you are suggesting, but they require a secondary model be fed into a primary model. We see this often in Natural Language Processing, where there is a model for how texts are similar (a word vector) and this model is then fed into another model that predicts things like text category and sentiment.

So basically, if you can model the similarities of your categorical variables (this is your secondary model), and feed that model into primary model, then you would only need update your secondary model when you get new data. But this approach has its issues...

Comment: can you give me a pointer regarding the issues as you mentioned in your last sentence. I have only a cursory knowledge of NLP but not a detailed background. I would like to know more about these issues. Thank you.

Comment: In the case of word vectors, the vector is a model of the semantic similarity of words (e.g. is "cat" a similar word to "dog"). In your case, you will need to model the similarity between the various vehicle types. In either situation, the issue is the use of estimators as an estimator. This can increase the biases and/or errors in your model. If you can remove the bias and account for the error, you will be fine, but that can be tricky.